# Can i stop contextMenuConfigurationForRowAt for specifc rows?

Tags: ios, swift

i have using contextMenuConfigurationForRowAt on my tableview but i want to enable/disable it based on data

is it possible of it should be execute for all cells at all?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/3295956-tableview)

> Use this method to provide a UIContextMenuConfiguration describing the menu to present. Return nil to prevent the interaction from beginning.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
     contextMenuConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, 
              point: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {
      return arr[indexPath.row].showMenu ? menu : nil
 }
```